# Undoing Git rebase --abort

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I had local changes in my repository. before push , i fetch from remote and did rebasing it shows some conflicts and i fixed it.

and then i tried to push my changes , before commit it shows `still need merge` so i did `rebase --abort` without commiting my changes.
after that my local changes was gone. 
i tried `git reflog` i dont find mine since i didnt `commit`.

I need my local changes how do i get it back? how `rebase --abort` delete my changes?

I did `rebase --continue`  once i fix conflict. since it says need update. then only i gave `rebase --abort`

Comment: Did you do `git rebase --continue` after each set of merge conflicts?  If so, then your working directory should be empty, and `git rebase --abort` should have had no effect.  My guess is that you didn't complete the rebase properly.  Your local changes may be lost.

Comment: yes i did still it shows need merges  .... thats why gave rebase --abort

Comment: When you aborted the rebase, you went back to the state you were in before rebase happened.  There is no workaround for this.  Just do the rebase over again, and this time don't make the same mistake.

Comment: Dude your Amazing ... thanks alot i got my changes back ... now feel like fly... post this as answer may help someone .. thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: i did rebase again it bring my changes back

Comment: Why is `git rebase --abort` so deconstructive? I, too, lost work during this. `--abort` implies "cancel". It should bring you back to the state it was before starting the rebase. This is a terrible pitfall, how to undo `git rebase` without wiping your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question along with what you commented above, it looks like you started a rebase, made some progress along the way, but did not complete it.  Instead, you typed `git rebase --abort`.  This effectively rolls back the entire rebase to the point where you were before you started the rebase.  There is no harm in aborting a rebase, save any work you already did resolving merge conflicts.

In any case, you should be able to just start the `rebase origin/<branch>` again.  This time around, just resolve the conflicts as each commit is applied by adding each conflicted file to the stage, and using `git rebase --continue`.  When all commits have been replayed, your rebased branch should be ready, with an empty working directory.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can right-click the root of your project go to **Local History**, and then **Show History**. You can now see all recent local changes and revert any files you want.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. Saved me hours of work, as well as reminded me why IntelliJ IDEA is the best IDE ever.

Comment: Another way to undo git rebase --abort (after deleting a branch locally that is on remote and recreating it from the default branch after pulling yours from upstream) and then manually apply your patches back on to it is to check your ``.git/logs/refs/heads/<branch name>`` file and then copy the commit sha hash from the commit you had on it before you did the command and then modify ``.git/refs/heads/<branch name>`` file to contain only that commit sha. After that you have successfully recovered from ``git rebase --abort``. Another reason why reflogs actually can save your hard work.

Comment: Similar option in VS code - `timeline`. But not helpful if you loose a newly created file

Answer (score 0):

Try

Resolve conflicts

1.

```
git add
```

2. 

```
git rebase --continue
```